# swiftui : tabview ios16 vs ios15** : glitchy and no animation

Tags: swift, swiftui, tabview, ios15, ios16

Since iOS16, I noticed a glitch when switching from tabN to tabN+1 or tabN-1 and reverse with complex embedded view. Also the animation to switch tab programmatically are no longer working when I use an observableObject as a selection :

```
@EnvironmentObject var ViewModel: VM
TabView(selection: $ViewModel.tabRouter) {
   View1()
      .tag("first")

   View2()
      .tag("second")

   View3()
      .tag("third")
}
.animation(.default, value: ViewModel.tabRouter)
.tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
.ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
```

On iOS15 everything works smoothly.
Best